# Send log messages as JSON

Tags: java, spring, logging, slf4j, zipkin

I am using spring boot in a project and currently exploring the logging behaviour. For that I'm using the zipkin service.

I have exported my logs to a json file using proper logback.xml:

```
{"@timestamp":"2018-07-12T17:53:44.613+05:30","@version":"1","message":"in meth3","logger_name":"com.example.demo.Controller.Controller","thread_name":"http-nio-8089-exec-3","level":"INFO","level_value":20000,"traceId":"62bcfafad3a37a09","spanId":"62bcfafad3a37a09","spanExportable":"true","X-Span-Export":"true","X-B3-SpanId":"62bcfafad3a37a09","X-B3-TraceId":"62bcfafad3a37a09","caller_class_name":"com.example.demo.Controller.Controller","caller_method_name":"meth3","caller_file_name":"Controller.java","caller_line_number":43,"appname":"pom.artifactId_IS_UNDEFINED","version":"pom.version_IS_UNDEFINED"}
```

Is there a way so that I could insert a jsonObject in my message part of the log. Something like:

```
logger.info(<some_json_object>)
```

I have tried searching a way extensively but to no avail. Is it even possible?

Comment: Zipkin is a trace collector. It has nothing to do with logging except the client instrumentation libraries optionally print trace information in log messages.

Answer (score 0):

The slf4j API only takes `String` as the input to the `info`, `debug`, `warn`, `error` messages.

What you could do is create your own JsonLogger wrapper, which takes a normal `Logger` (maybe wraps around it), which you could include at the top of your classes like:

`private static final JsonLogger logger = new JsonLogger(LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class))`;

You can then use Jackson, GSON or your favourite object to JSON mapper inside your JsonLogger so that you could do what you want. It can then offer the `info`, `debug`, `warn`, `error` methods like a normal logger.

You can also create your own `JsonLoggerFactory` which encapsulates this for you so that the line to include in each class is more concise.